# internal server error on $.ajax call in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "AppForm.aspx/ValidateIFSC",
    data: "{'BannkIFSC':'" + $("#<%=ui_txtIFSCCode.ClientID %>").val() + "'}",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    async: true,
    cache: false,
    success: function (result) {
        boo = result.d
    }
});
```

It's working fine in local, but it is not working on the server.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var xx = $("#<%=ui_txtIFSCCode.ClientID %>").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "AppForm.aspx/ValidateIFSC",
       // data: "{'BannkIFSC':'" + JSON.stringify(xx) + "'}",
        data:'{"BannkIFSC":"'+ JSON.stringify(xx)+'"}',
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        success: function (result) { boo = result.d }
```